# Genetic Programming in Agent Based Modeling with NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, agent-based-modeling

I have an Agent-Based model written in NetLogo. Now I want to take it to next level and evolve my agents as Genetic Programming population. I want a way to incorporate the genetic programming part into my NetLogo model, either through an interface or write it in NetLogo itself if that's possible. Anybody has any insights into this?

Thank you

Comment: The the `GenJam - Duple` model in the bundled NetLogo models library uses a genetic algorithm to change the beats it creates.  That might be a useful reference, depending on what you're trying to do.